# how to implement search API in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, search

I have Text Input like this

```
  <CustomInput
            value={searchInput}
            onChangeText={(e) => func(e)}
            mainStyle={{ width: "81%" }}
            placeholder="Search"
          />
```

Now I have func like this

```
const func = async (searchText) => {
    setSearchInput(searchText);
    searchAPI();
  };
```

this is my API calling code

```
const searchAPI = async () => {
    try {
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append("string_search", searchInput);
      setActivityIndicatorVal(true);
      let response = await fetch(
        "APILINK",
        {
          method: "POST",
          body: data,
          header: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        }
      );
      var json = await response.json();
      if (json.status == 1) {
        setActivityIndicatorVal(false);
        setList(json.data);
      } else {
        setActivityIndicatorVal(false);
        console.log("Error");
        getServiceList();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setActivityIndicatorVal(false);

      Alert.alert("Error", "Error Massage : " + e, [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
          style: "cancel",
        },
        { text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("OK Pressed") },
      ]);
      return;
    }
  };
```

Now my question is Result is searing and showing correctly as I started typing in text box. But I remove all text from text input by back pressing keyboard button. then It should show all result. But it only showing That keyword which I remove recently by back press keyboard button. please help thanks.

Comment: perhaps the issue is in the functions `setSearchInput` and/or `searchAPI` - the code you have shown doesn't seem to have any issue, since it doesn't show how the "Result" is obtained - Also- does *back press keyboard button* mean *press backspace on the keyboard*?

Comment: search on Youtube see exactly what i want. start typing something in youtube search box and then see results and then start removing text and then see the result

Comment: yes, I know what you want, but you haven't shown the code you are having an issue with - clearly you have implemented the search (since you're getting results) but the code you've shown does not show how you are getting results, and that's where your issue is, the code you've written, but haven't shown, is where your problem is

Comment: ok so shall i show you my API calling code. please check updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the user typing, `searchAPI` receives old input value due to how to React state update and component rendering works.

Try this refactor.

```js
const func = async (searchText) => {
    setSearchInput(searchText);
  
  //This function execute before component rerender.
  // always pass input text value not rely on state value
    searchAPI(searchText);
  };
```

Then `searchAPI`

```js
const searchAPI = async (searchQuery) => {
    try {
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append("string_search", searchQuery);
      setActivityIndicatorVal(true);
      let response = await fetch(
        "APILINK",
        {
          method: "POST",
          body: data,
          header: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        }
      );
      var json = await response.json();
      if (json.status == 1) {
        setActivityIndicatorVal(false);
        setList(json.data);
      } else {
        setActivityIndicatorVal(false);
        console.log("Error");
        getServiceList();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setActivityIndicatorVal(false);

      Alert.alert("Error", "Error Massage : " + e, [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
          style: "cancel",
        },
        { text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("OK Pressed") },
      ]);
      return;
    }
  };
```

You can improve user experience and save server resources by debouncing search queries and only querying the database when the user finishes typing the search query.

```js
// Utilitiy debounce function

function debounce(fn, wait) {
  var timeout;
  return function () {
    var ctx = this,
      args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
      fn.apply(ctx, args);
    }, wait || 500);
  };
}

const debouncedSearch = debounce(func, 500);

<CustomInput
    onChangeText={debouncedSearch}
    mainStyle={{ width: "81%" }}
    placeholder="Search"
  />
```